# How to force descendant classes to implement an abstract function?

Tags: delphi, inheritance, abstract

I have a base abstract class in which I have defined a virtual abstract function.

```
TMyBaseClass = class abstract(TForm)
public
  function MyFunction : string; virtual; abstract;
end;
```

I have noticed that no error/warning is shown when compiling a not abstract descendant class.

```
TMyDescendantClass = class(TMyBaseClass);
```

The goal is that to force my colleagues to implement the function for every descendant class. I found a similar question ([Delphi 6: Force compiler error on missing abstract class methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120220/delphi-6-force-compiler-error-on-missing-abstract-class-methods)) but the solution doesn't fit to my goal.

**Update1:**

Classes are obtained by calling "GetClass" function.

```
GetClass('TMyDescendantClass').Create
```

Due to this fact, instances creation doesn't cause warnings.

Comment: @RBA: I'm not really familiar with interfaces but I think an interface would force me to define "MyFunction" for TMyBaseClass, instead of forcing who write TMyBaseClass descendants to define it. It's true?

Comment: Virtual abstract methods are the solution. You'll see warnings if you instantiate an object with unimplemented abstract methods. Using an interface will probably just add complication. Even if you don't see the warnings, your program won't work and will fail with a runtime error if anyone fails to implement the abstract methods. Since you aren't going to ship your code without running it first, there's nothing to fear.

Comment: That could get annoying if they want their concrete class to inherit from their own abstract base class. (i.e. TConcClass -> TAbsClass -> TMyBaseClass)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you stick to your current design there's nothing you can do beyond waiting for an error at runtime.

If you were referring to the classes statically then you would see warnings if you instantiated classes that contained abstract methods. But because you obtain the classes dynamically, the compiler cannot help you.

Adding an interface to the class wouldn't be much use. Suppose you changed your class so that it implemented an interface? You'd have to implement that in the base class. How would you do so? By using virtual methods? You'd just be back where you started.

Suppose you could somehow force the implementers of derived classes to implement all these abstract methods. What is stopping them from doing so like this:

```
type
  TMyDescendantClass = class(TMyBaseClass)
  public
    function MyFunction: string; override;
  end;

function TMyDescendantClass.MyFunction: string;
begin
  // TODO: implement this method
end;
```

Sometimes a contract just cannot be enforced at compile time!

---

Rather then using abstract methods of classes, you could change tack completely. Don't ask the implementers to derive from a base class. Ask them to supply you with an interface when you request it. That puts the onus on them. They have to implement the interface (and instantiate it). Then they are obliged to implement each function. Not that it stops them from implementing the functions incorrectly of course!

Depending on factors that only you know, that may prove less convenient than your current design. But only you can decide that.

Answer (score 3):

A somewhat ugly solution would be triggering a **runtime** exception early on, precluding any use of their descendent classes unless they did the implementation:

```
 TMyBaseClass = class 
   public function MyFunction : string; virtual; abstract;
   public procedure AfterConstruction; override;
 end;

....

procedure TMyBaseClass.AfterConstruction; override;
begin
  MyFunction();
  inherited;
end;
```

This is providing that the function itself is pure ( not changing the object state and not requiring much of the object state ) and cheap at execution costs.

Some optimizations might also include one-time testing only for the first instantiation and binding this to debug-builds only.

```
 TMyBaseClass = class 
   public function MyFunction : string; virtual; abstract;
   public procedure AfterConstruction; override;
   private class var MyFunction_tested: Boolean;
 end;

....

procedure TMyBaseClass.AfterConstruction; override;
begin
  {$IfOpt D+}
  if not MyFunction_tested then begin
    MyFunction();
    MyFunction_tested := true; 
  end;
  {$EndIf}
  inherited;
end;
```

---

UPDATE.

> Classes are obtained by calling "GetClass" function.
>   `GetClass('TMyDescendantClass').Create`

So, you use late binding, where the program core (and compiler) do not actually know which classes they would be extended with by plugins made by third-party developers. Granted, practically you may have a fixed list of plugins and a fixed list of their developers, but for the program structure that makes no difference. You program just is not defined yet during compilation phase, only the specific set of runtime plugins defines it completely.

That means you really can not test it all when compiling your core program. Any person at any later time can implement a brand new plugin and jack it in. Your Delphi just cannot see into the future. So you do have to resort to runtime checking. That is just how plugins-based LEGO-like applications work.

The problem now becomes how to arrange that runtime check, so it would be as "greedy" as possible (failing always => failing early: during in-house testing phase, rather than few months after deployment) and at the same time it would consume as little runtime resources as possible.

Actually, checking for one and only one specific function seems questionable idea per se. Using RTTI you might check if ANY abstract function still remains.
Granted, using RTTI is relatively slow, but I think loading BPL files from HDD would be slower anyway, so it matters little here.

Personally I think you should separate two different operations - obtaining the class and instantiating it. Just like it is done in Java and DotNet runtimes, where there are dedicated class checkers/verifiers in-between these operations.

```
  TmpClass := GetClass('TMyDescendantClass');
  if not TmpClass.InheritsFrom( TMyBaseForm ) then 
     raise EPluginSystemMisconfiguration.Create(.....); 
  MyPluginFormClass := TMyBaseForm( TmpClass ); 
  VerifyPluginClass( MyPluginFormClass ); // immediately raises exception if class is not valid
  MyPluginForm := MyPluginFormClass.create(Application);
```

What checks should `VerifyPluginClass` implement is up to you. But one of the checks should be if the class has ANY abstract non-implemented functions.

See [How i can determine if an abstract method is implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305008)

If possible, try to establish practice of regular unit-testing or integration-testing - then that very `VerifyPluginClass` subroutine would be reused in the testing framework, providing your co-developers to catch this kind of their errors themselves.

Comment: Would you ever include this in your code? I know I would not. Worse than ugly, it's appalling. 5 upvotes! Astounding. I wish people would vote based on the quality of posts rather than sympathy and pity.

Comment: Well, if it would be my decision, I would just say that failure of others to properly implement a class is their failure not mine. But however if boss would say "fix it at any cost and do it at your side" - then I would face a choice between "ugly hack" and resigning. I guess every practical programmer had cases when he fell back to ugly hacks, finding no way to implement elegant and haute couture solution.

Comment: I think I'd resign!

Comment: This solution is ugly - and that is what I started with. It is also not really a solution, it does not fail at compilation time. This is also not runtime unit-testing. Still it gives at least something. The generic "remove the problematic class and write your program into some different way which would not require that class at all" is also not a solution, it is too abstract to be one.

Comment: That choice belongs to the topicstarter. We all have our personal thresholds when and where it gets "too much". But they are exactly that - personal.

Comment: You did not suggest removing the problematic class, so not sure what that refers to.

Comment: The second part of your answer. "Change the task completely"

Comment: I was talking about this answer, not any other ones. Perhaps the asker is constrained to a specific design, perhaps not. Neither of us really know. What I don't understand is the voting here. Was that generated by your complaints about receiving a few downvotes over the past month? It makes no sense for such an appalling idea to be so popular.

Comment: Well, that complain possibly made some people to go to my profile and check my few last answers. Whether they gave me upvotes for mere sympathy or their dismay of non-substantiated downvotes, or did they  paid extra attention to me and my answers but then genuinely upvoted them on their own merits - that I can not know. I'd prefer the latter, of course. /// Also, living in practical world, we do sometimes resort to ugly hacks when finding ourself in a dead-end. So if an ugly solution is offered and frankly and overtly marked as ugly - I see it more like necessary evil than a pitfall.

Comment: Personally, I have a suspicion the real case here is extending the base class with new abstract methods. Then derived class implementers just overlook that change (was it even documented as breaking change?) and keep compiling their old implementations, made against the old version of the base class, that lacked those methods back then. Just speculating, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Declaring a class containing abstract methods is not a problem, and no warning is issued here; a problem my arise if you create an instance of an abstract class, and Delphi compiler issues a correspondent warning. For example,

```
var
  Obj: TMyDescendantClass;

begin
  Obj:= TMyDescendantClass.Create;
  ...
```

leads to the warning

> [DCC Warning]: W1020 Constructing instance of 'TMyDescendantClass'
>   containing abstract method 'TMyBaseClass.MyFunction'

Comment: This warning also can be converted to an Error, if he has control over his colleagues Delphi settings. But he seems to have not. And then those colleagues can just prohibit this warning.

Comment: In real scenario, classes are forms who are defined in dynamic packages. These classes are obtained by calling "GetClass" function (i.e  GetClass('TMyDescendantClass').Create). So, instances creation doesn't cause warnings.

Comment: If that detail matters, it should be in the question. Otherwise it's your problem and not ours.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: You're right, it matters. I've updated the question by adding this detail.

Answer (score 2):

If the descendant classes are declared as sealed then the compiler raises errors for any abstract procedures and functions that remain unimplemented. So the following will raise an error at compile time:

```
TMyBaseClass = class abstract(TForm)
public
  function MyFunction : string; virtual; abstract;
end;

TMyDescendantClass = class sealed(TMyBaseClass);
```

Of course you cannot force your colleagues to declare the class as sealed but perhaps it helps.

Answer (score 0):

A small hint, how to force to make better code: use **-W^** as additional compiler directive. [image: Project options]

It will threat all warnings as errors and you would not be able to compile your code such as without implementing abstract methods.
And you must use **virtual**, not **dynamic** for directive to work (as of Delphi 10.4). Since you use late binding, directive would not help, but it sure would fix warnings in your code forcing everyone to fix them.